# why is the status Exited (-1) when docker stop some container

Tags: docker

When I run the docker-run and start a container, but however, when I stop the container by "docker stop 3efffea39f2f", the status is Exited (-1) but not Exited (0), why?
3efffea39f2f        sbox:latest         "uvm_sboxsvr_start -   3 minutes ago       Exited (-1) 48 seconds ago                                         grave_heisenberg

Comment: The exit status is whatever is returned by the process running at PID1 inside the container. So to answer you question we'd need to see your Dockerfile and how you start your container `docker run ...`

Comment: ah, wait, my image is built and the command is some long...
/usr/bin/docker run -e SBOXPORT=5912 -e DISPLAY=:1    -v /BGconf/eth2/network.cfg:/etc/network.cfg -u 536 --env HOME=/home/async083 -w /home/async083 -e HOSTNAME=ZS-ISP --net=none -d sbox uvm_sboxsvr_start -p 1 -s 'local.async083@192.168.10.111:zone2' -g 1920x1080 -h /home/async083 -a 0 -l 1 -u 1 -x ' -noclipboardrecv -noclipboardsend' async083
this is our command to start the container.

Comment: Can you update your post with dockerfile and run comands docker, thus is more readable  to answer your question.